# The Background Image for my Personal Website not showing up. I think my path is correct url('../images/IMG_1.png) but not sure

Tags: html, css, github, frontend, background-image

I'm pretty new to cs and wanted to try and create a personal website for fun.
I've attempted many times to try and use an image from my files to be the background for my personal website. I tried to read up on how paths work but I can't seem to be able to set the background to the image.

Please check my github repository for all the code:
https://github.com/HarnoorDhillon/HarnoorDhillon.github.io

Comment: Can you add the code to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked out your git repo and it looks like there's an error with your image. It's broken or something. But for the style.css you might want to put `background-image: url("../images/IMG_1.png");` under the body instead of html as that is generally where that sort of stuff goes.

For example,

```
body { 
    background-image: url("../images/IMG_1.png");
   /* Other stuff like background-color, font, etc.*/
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for so long haha.

Comment: @Harnoor No worries! Good luck with the rest

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: That image is more than 3800 x 2600px and nearly 16MB, which is kinda huge, even for a full screen background image. You could comfortably half the dimensions (which would roughly quarter the file size/download time) with no discernible loss of visual clarity.